# Como adicionar marca de referência em PDF com Itext 5.14

Tags: java, itext

Preciso que meu rodapé contenha uma descrição para uma marca de referência, pra quem não sabe são aqueles números que ficam elevados em uma palavra, e são referenciados no rodapé com uma explicação daquele conteúdo. Ja possuo o método para criar o rodapé, porém não consigo encontrar como colocar o número de referência.

```
 Font fonteTimes = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 10, 
 Font.NORMAL);
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
 table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
 table.addCell("*marca1* e explicação");

 table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(document.leftMargin()), 
 table.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(document.bottomMargin()), 
 writer.getDirectContent());
```

Tenho criada uma lista com sublistas. Onde essas possuem itens que são basicamente Paragraph. Esses itens possuem informações de leis, que deverão ser explicadas no rodapé.
Estou criando as listas da seguinte forma:

```
List listaRomana = new RomanList();
listaRomana.add(new ListItem(new Paragraph("item1:", fonteNegrito)));

ArrayList<String> relatorio = new ArrayList<>();
relatorio.add("Fundamento na Lei Federal n° 19.003/1998*marca1*");
List subLista1 = criaSubLista(relatorio, fonte, true, false);
```

---

```
private List criaSubLista(ArrayList<String> itens, Font fonte, boolean 
   ehNumber, boolean ehLetra) {

 List subLista = new List(ehNumber, ehLetra);
 for (String descricao : itens) {
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph(descricao, fonte);
    subLista.add(new ListItem(para));
 }
 return subLista;
 }
```

Isso é basicamente o que tenho, depois de criar a lista e sub-lista, eu as adiciono no *Document*.
Como é possível perceber, dentro da sublista eu passo uma frase com uma lei, essa deve possuir uma marca de referência, e quero poder referenciá-la no rodapé

Comment: Envie mais código, para possamos melhor te ajudar

Comment: Adicionei novas informações, preciso logo de algum meio para fazer funcionar o documento